# Distance travelled by centre of circle.

Tags: geometry

Imagine a wheel rolling on a floor. In a span of time $∆t$, is the distance travelled by the centre of circle equal to Arc length covered by radius?

In other words,
[image]

In the picture let $x$ denote the distance travelled by the centre of circle in a time $∆t$. At the same time let $S$ be arc length covered by the radius. Then is,
$$S=x$$?

Comment: It's infact true

Comment: Yes you are right!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and the way to see that is to imagine that the circle is a disk with wet paint on its circumference. Then, as the circle moves through an arc length of $s$, there is a trail of paint of length $s$ from the starting point to the end and the center of the circle is always over the end of the paint trail.